# Declaring type in fetch function

Tags: typescript, next.js

[Screenshot of fetch function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zy6K5.png)
I am trying to fetch information from notion database in a Next.js Typescript project. So far I'm getting the error to set up type for databse_id value. How do I declare its type?

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: Also, please post your [code and messages / output as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_NOTION_DB` returns a value of type `string | undefined`.
You can avoid the error either checking that it is not `undefined`:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
    if (!process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_NOTION_DB) return { props: { }}
    const res = await notion.database.query({
        database_id: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_NOTION_DB
    })
    ...
};
```

Or, providing a default value to it:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
    const res = await notion.database.query({
        database_id: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_NOTION_DB || ''
    })
    ...
};
```